# How to limit requests per USER in ServletAPI (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

How can I allow only a one request to micorservice method with specific URL `@PathVariable` per User.
My Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/product", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public class ProductRestController {
    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    ProductAsm productAsm;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ID/{ID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ProductResource> getProductID(@PathVariable("ID") Long ID, @AuthenticationPrincipal User) {

        Product product = productService.getProduct(ID);
        if (product == null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(productAsm.toResource(product), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

For example :

1. first request `/rest/product/ID/2231` allowed for USER(with login="xaxa" )
2. second request `/rest/product/ID/2545` allowed for USER(with login="xaxa" )
3. thirdth request `/rest/product/ID/2231` not allowed for USER(with login="xaxa" )

Which is the best way to implement this functionality?(Have I to keep this URL request with User login in DB or there is already solutions)

Comment: How many unique IDs do you have to support? I have a few ideas but their usability depends on this numbers. Also - do you consider a possibility that some IDs can have throughput <> 1 ?

Comment: at first there is a few id (around 100-500) but in future it can increase to 5000

Comment: No, I did not consider this possibility!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use AOP and implement your own aspect that would be called Before your Rest Endpoint method.

This pointcut would read ID provided in a request and would try to find a Lock corresponding with this ID. Then the usual - try to access resource and potentially wait.

Implementation could base on Guava's [Striped](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.java) class - at least for the start.

There are several problems that need to be taken into consideration:

1. Striped could be replaced with some LRU Cache for better memory management.
2. You would of course have to provide synchronization for the case when the same ID is accessed simultaneously by two requests.
3. It would work only for an application deployed on a single node.
4. It would not be very good approach performance-wise. Depending on your traffic this may be an issue.